# OnTriggerExit not triggering in Unity

Tags: triggers, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on an exam project, where I'm using TUIO as an input device for my Unity setup. The idea is to use fiducials to create various inputs (in this case the values 1 though 6, to simulate an ordinary six-sided die), that will then be registered within Unity. OnTriggerEnter works fine with my current setup, correctly changing the color of tiles based on the 1-6 input. OnTriggerExit however, which is supposed to change the tile color to white when the tiles are not being triggered, never triggers. The problem seems to be that the TUIO setup creates clones of the in-engine prefabs, which disappear after the corresponding input device is removed. Thus, Unity doesn't register that the trigger "exits" as it should, since the object simply just disappears entirely. I have tried countless solutions, but none have worked so far.

Here is the code I have been using for my triggers.

```
function Start () {

}

function Update () {
}

function OnTriggerEnter (other: Collider) {
if (other.CompareTag("Player")) {
renderer.material.color = Color.red;
}
}

function OnTriggerExit (other: Collider) {
if (other.CompareTag("Player")) {
renderer.material.color = Color.white;
}
}
```

Comment: Suggest reading the [Unity physics docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/comp-DynamicsGroup.html).  Specifically the `colliders` section near the buttom.  Each collider page has a collision matrix at the bottom showing what events happen and when.

Comment: Link is dead, new location : http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PhysicsSection.html